# Delete script after execution

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, execution

I have a script that redirects me to the english version of a page if I entered NOT from with russian browser. But my script doesn't allow me to switch languages on the page (it just keeps redirecting me).

The script:

```html
<script>
const uri = window.location;
const lang = window.navigator.language;
if (uri.href.indexOf('lang') < 0) {
    if (lang != 'ru-RU') {
        eng = window.location.href.includes('https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/en/');
        console.log(eng);
        if (eng == false) {
            const re = "https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/";
            const url = window.location.href;
            const newstr = url.replace(re, 'https://www.fashiondance.in.ua/en/');
            window.location.href = newstr;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

How can I remove the script after execution for all sessions using php?

Comment: Hi Alex, it looks like pure javascript code. Adding a PHP tag is not relevant.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I forgot

Comment: @Exception wait, I can delete it with php, because I need to delete it from whole session, not only page